# Excelsheet created using Apache-POI doesn't have header

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Below snippet exports the resultset data to the excel file  however it does not creates the headers.
I have used

`HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);` to create header but the created excel sheet contains only data with no headers. what can be the issue?.Please guide.

```
public boolean prepareExcelFilefromQuery(Collection<List> queryDataRowWise,HttpServletResponse response)        
    HSSFRow row = null;
                HSSFCell cell=null;
                Integer rowCounter=0;
                Integer colCounter;
                boolean success=false;
                try {

                    Iterator<List> rowIterator = queryDataRowWise.iterator();

                    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Zero_Report_N");

                    HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

                      rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("APPLN_RECD_DT");
                    rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("POLICY_NO");
                    rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("APPLN_NO");
                    rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("OR_NUMBER");


                    while(rowIterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        colCounter=0;

                        queryDataColWise=(List)rowIterator.next();

                        Iterator colIterator = queryDataColWise.iterator();

                        row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter++);
                        while(colIterator.hasNext())
                        {
                            cell = row.createCell(colCounter++);


                            Object o = colIterator.next();

                            if(o instanceof java.lang.String )
                            {   
                                String s=(String)o;
                                cell.setCellValue(s);
                            }
                            else if(o instanceof java.lang.Double )
                            {
                                Double d=(Double)o;
                                cell.setCellValue(d);
                            }
                            else if(o instanceof java.lang.Integer )
                            {
                                Integer i=(Integer)o;
                                cell.setCellValue(i);
                            }
                            else if(o instanceof java.util.Date )
                            {   
                                Date date=(Date)o;

                                SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER;              

                                FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
                                String date11 = FORMATTER.format(date);     

                                HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                                cellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy"));
                                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                                cell.setCellValue(FORMATTER.parse(date11));
                            }
                        }
                    }

        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
                success=true;
    catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Exception caught in prepareExcelFilefromQuery class ", e);
                }
        return success;
    }
```

where expReportDetailCol contains resulteset data `Collection<List> expReportDetailCol = new ArrayList<List>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `++rowCounter` not `rowCounter++`. `rowCounter++` means give me the current value, then increment. Your rowCounter value is zero to start, so your first set of data overwrites it

Either increment rowCounter when you're done with the header, or use ++rowCounter instead

Answer (score 0):

HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Zero_Report_N");
// after creating sheet

u can add headers by putting in arraylist

```
  HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(i);//u can pass values of headers
    cell.setCellValue(value);
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
```